# Editing template in auto hosted joomla

Tags: joomla

How do I customise the template, mainly edit the top banner on
http://www.marisa.jhost.co.uk/

The joomla was auto setup and hosted, I seem to have no access to the file structure. (If I do I don't know how/where!)

I have found the templates in the Joomla Administrator (v1.8) under site template manager but there is no option to edit any of the templates or ability to upload a different one.

I just want to change the banner and the colours, help please!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can install extensions you could use an ftp component to do some basic file editing through the admin interface. I find [ninjaXplorer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/file-management/4746) to be the best one.

Answer (score 1):

Try [eXtplorer component](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/file-management/2630). It is "Editors Pick" extension.

eXtplorer is a web-based File Management Component for all your needs. It has a desktop-application-like interface with drag&drop, grid and a directory tree and makes heavy use of the ExtJS Javascript Library.
You can use it to access and modify the files and directories on your server via FTP or direct file access.